# Natural sorting

Tags: python, regex, sorting, natural-sort

I have some files that need to be sorted by name, unfortunately I can't use a regular sort, because I also want to sort the numbers in the string, so I did some research and found that what I am looking for is called [natural sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order).

I tried the solution given [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/285264-natural-string-sorting/#c3) and it worked perfectly.

However, for strings like `PresserInc-1_10.jpg` and `PresserInc-1_11.jpg` which causes that specific natural key algorithm to fail, because it only matches the first integer which in this case would be `1` and `1`, and so it throws off the sorting. So what I think might help is to match all numbers in the string and group them together, so if I have `PresserInc-1_11.jpg` the algorithm should give me `111` back, so my question is, is this possible ?

Here's a list of filenames:

`files = ['PresserInc-1.jpg', 'PresserInc-1_10.jpg', 'PresserInc-1_11.jpg', 'PresserInc-10.jpg', 'PresserInc-2.jpg', 'PresserInc-3.jpg', 'PresserInc-4.jpg', 'PresserInc-5.jpg', 'PresserInc-6.jpg', 'PresserInc-11.jpg']`

Comment: I don't get your question...Please post a more clear input and expected output

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Google: Python natural sorting](http://www.google.com/search?q=Python+natural+sorting).

[Result 1](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/285264-natural-string-sorting/): The page you linked to.

**But don't stop there!**

[Result 2](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html): Jeff Atwood's blog that explains how to do it properly.

[Result 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort): An answer I posted based on Jeff Atwood's blog.

Here's the code from that answer:

```
import re

def natural_sort(l): 
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower() 
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key)] 
    return sorted(l, key=alphanum_key)
```

Results for your data:

```
PresserInc-1.jpg
PresserInc-1_10.jpg
PresserInc-1_11.jpg
PresserInc-2.jpg
PresserInc-3.jpg
etc...
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/xKWL4)

Comment: No spaces in `key=alphanum_key` please

Comment: Thanks, you're right shouldn't stop there :), bit tired though.. Thanks :)

Comment: Result 1: This stack overflow page.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind third party libraries, you can use [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) to achieve this.

```
>>> import natsort
>>> files = ['PresserInc-1.jpg', 'PresserInc-1_10.jpg', 'PresserInc-1_11.jpg', 'PresserInc-10.jpg', 'PresserInc-2.jpg', 'PresserInc-3.jpg', 'PresserInc-4.jpg', 'PresserInc-5.jpg', 'PresserInc-6.jpg', 'PresserInc-11.jpg']
>>> natsort.natsorted(files)
['PresserInc-1.jpg',
 'PresserInc-1_10.jpg',
 'PresserInc-1_11.jpg',
 'PresserInc-2.jpg',
 'PresserInc-3.jpg',
 'PresserInc-4.jpg',
 'PresserInc-5.jpg',
 'PresserInc-6.jpg',
 'PresserInc-10.jpg',
 'PresserInc-11.jpg']
```