# sort string by number inside

Tags: python, string, int

I would like to know how can I sort a string by the number inside.

As example I have:

```
hello = " hola %d" % (number_from_database)
bye = "adios %d" % (number_from_database_again)
```

I want to sort them by the number even if it changes.

Comment: Do you have a list of these to sort? Sort them compared to what?

Comment: for example sometimes the user can sorts in the web "bye" before than hello so hello = "hola 2" and bye = "adios 1" or sometimes the user can sorts hello before bye so i want to know how to sort them bye the number inside, thank you :D

Comment: That doesn't make this any clearer. Sorting applies to a sequence of items; all you have is two variables, `hello` and `bye`.

Comment: This is called "natural" sorting, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11150239/989121 and the links therein for examples.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass a key to sort:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(re.sub('\D', '', x)))
```

For example:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: l = ['asdas2', 'asdas1', 'asds3ssd']

In [3]: sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(re.sub('\D', '', x)))
Out[3]: ['asdas1', 'asdas2', 'asds3ssd']
```

Where `re.sub('\D', '', x)` replaces [everything but the digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450897/python-removing-characters-except-digits-from-string).

Comment: Man, you are like a god that works, thanks  for your answer I do not know how can i thank you. God Bless you

Comment: But I have 14 reputation tu opvote I require 15, I'll upvote when i have 15

Answer (score 1):

Just a little complement to Andy's answer.

If you want to sort set which also contain strings without any number:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: int('0'+re.sub('\D', '', x)))
```

, which would put those strings without any number at the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above do not work for strings with the format:

```
test 8 - test 18
```

The following code will return `818` instead of `8`:

```py
x = 'test 8 - test 18'
res = int(re.sub(r'\D', '', x))
print(res)

>>> 818
```

The solution for this is doing a `search` and getting the `group` result:

```py
x = 'test 8 - test 18'
res = int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group())
print(res)

>>> 8
```

So, the final solution with this correction is:

```py
l = [
   'test 9 - test 8',
   'test 8 - test 18'
]

l2 = sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group()))

print(l)
print(l2)

>>> ['test 9 - test 8', 'test 8 - test 18']
['test 8 - test 18', 'test 9 - test 8']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
salutations = [hello, bye]
salutations.sort(key=lambda x: int(filter(lambda s: s.isdigit(), x.split())[0]))
```