# Smart sorting in python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I am trying to sort tuples in list that have field of mixed nature: LABEL.NUMBER. For example:

```
 aaaa.143
 aadf.23
 aaaa.8
 ..
```

So, I would like to sort first by LABEL as strings, and at the same by NUMBER as numbers, i.e. after sorting the should come:

```
 aaaa.8
 aaaa.143
 aadf.23
 ..
```

I have now the following:

```
for i in sorted(v_distribution.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
```

which sorts using the whole filed as a string, so I get:

```
 aaaa.143
 aaaa.8
 aadf.23
 ..
```

How should I modify my lambda function to do the task?

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150239/python-natural-sorting

Comment: @JonClements No, thank you for the link, I need to check the solution, maybe my question is to be duplicated...

Comment: @JonClements It turned out that solution posted here solves my specific task instead of general solution from your link. So I think it's not fully duplicate but a special case regarding the similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with lambda as:

```
for i in sorted(v_distribution.items(), key=lambda x: (x.split('.', 1)[0], int(x.split('.', 1)[1]):
```

Comment: Yes, this works now and turned out to be very easy modification, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
>>> s = ['aaaa.143', 'aadf.23', 'aaaa.8']
>>> def key_f(x):
...     head, tail = x.split('.', 1)
...     return (head, int(tail))
...
>>> sorted(s, key=key_f)
['aaaa.8', 'aaaa.143', 'aadf.23']
```

Although this can be done with `lambda`, it is better to separate key calculation into separate function.

Comment: Thank you, since it was tagged with lambda and tuples was in question, I will accept another answer, +1 anyway