# Python list.sort() not working/showing odd behaviour

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a very odd problem with the Python `list.sort()` function.

In my program I get a list of files via `os.listdir()`. This will return something like

```
['0.jpg', '1.jpg', '10.jpg', '11.jpg', '12.jpg', '13.jpg', '14.jpg', '15.jpg', '16.jpg', '17.jpg', '18.jpg', '19.jpg', '2.jpg', '20.jpg']
```

*(The problem with this list is, that the second to last element should be at the third position and 3.jpg - 9.jpg are somewhere at the end of the list.)*
Now I want to get the last element in this list (the one with the highest number) so i do a `list.sort()`.

Strangely this doesn´t do anything to the list. I also tried `sorted(list)` which also returns the exact same list. So I opened up the interpreter and told it to sort the list `["3.jpg","2.jpg","5.jpg"]`, which for some reason **did** work.

*So my question is: Can **anybody** please tell my why python doesn´t sort the first list, but the second one is fine? Also, how would I solve this problem, is there some workaround?*

In case anyone´s interested: here´s my code:

```
li=os.listdir("screenshots")
li.sort()
print(li)
```

Comment: Why should `2.jpg` come before `10.jpg`?  Do you put `C` before `BA`?

Comment: You're comparing strings, not numbers.  For example, alphabetically `"10" < "2"`.

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python sorts strings in lexical ordering.  "10" comes before "2" because 1 < 2.

In order to change how it sorts the list, you can use the `key=` parameter.  Assuming the file names are just numbers, you can use

`li.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0]))`

This separates out the filename and converts it into a number, then uses that number as the key for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order). You can do natural sorting in python using this code (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11150413/5189607)):

```
import re

def natural_sort(l): 
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower() 
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key)] 
    return sorted(l, key=alphanum_key)
```