# Sorting query in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having very basic query that I want to achieve something like this:

```
<some work>
for f in glob('a1*.txt*'):
    <some work>
```

I am having `a1.txt`, `a2.txt`, `a3.txt`, ......,`a10.txt`, `a11.txt`, ....,`a100.txt`.

I want to process file like `a1.txt` ,`a2.txt`, `a3.txt` ,...

When I am selecting files in the `for` loop, it does not appear in a sequence like `a1.txt, a2.txt, a3.txt` it is appearing like `a1.txt, a10.txt ...`etc.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python natural sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150239/python-natural-sorting)

Answer (score 0):

It is lexically sorted like you would expect strings., natural sort is not provided by Python built-in libraries. You can use external or below mentioned way.

I assume all filenames are same apart from the number part.

```
>>> sorted(glob.glob('a*.txt*'), key=lambda x: int(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x.strip('a')))[0]))
['a1.txt,', 'a2.txt,', 'a10.txt']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help it is working fine o/p ['a1.txt', 'a2.txt', 'a3.txt', 'a10.txt', 'a30.txt'] can you pl explain me the command specially int(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x.strip('a')))[0]))

Answer (score -1):

As I understand correctly you want just one number after `a`. To achieve this you can use regex.

```
import os
import re

def re_glob(pattern, path):
    return filter(re.compile(pattern).match, os.listdir(path))
list(re_glob(r"a.\.txt", "."))
```

Result:

```
['a0.txt',
 'a1.txt',
 'a2.txt',
 'a3.txt',
 'a4.txt',
 'a5.txt',
 'a6.txt',
 'a7.txt',
 'a8.txt',
 'a9.txt']
```